# List All Rows Containing Duplicates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to List All Rows Containing Duplicates by a name in the table for instance, name = TestName or TestName1 or Test name 2..
but also want to know what else is attached to them..

I have done this query.

```
select firstname,lastname from table
group by firstname,lastname
having count(*) > 1
```

I have found duplicated records but you're interested in getting all the information attached to them, however this is all on one table..

I have tried to do this..

`select * from my_table a join ( select firstname, lastname  from my_table  group by firstname, lastname  having count(*) > 1 ) b on a.firstname = b.firstname and a.lastname = b.lastname`

but this is if the data was on 2 separate tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by firstname, lastname) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: from table t.
) t
is the t after the bracket the table name?

Comment: @AndyThomas . . . No.  It is a table alias.